# Javascript params from string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I want to set dynamic parameters for the TagEditor (*or any other plugin that has parameters*) plugin according to an array of paramaters in string (from php), I have a div in this way.

```
<textarea class="tag-editor" type="text" name="xxxx" data-attributes-js="{placeholder:'1,2,3,4',other_para,:true,....}"></textarea>
```

So in the JS I want to obtain those parameters and return them evaluated so that tagEditor works with those dynamic parameters.

```
var $input = $('.tag-editor');
$input.tagEditor( $input.attr("data-attributes-js") );
```

but this does not work, how can I make this work this way?

Comment: You need to turn the string value of data-attributes-json into a javascript object using JSON.parse.  However, your json is not well formed (missing double quotes around property names/values).

Comment: The important concept here is **[serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)**. You are trying to **serialize** some data in PHP using JSON then **deserialize** it in JS. You don't necessarily need to use a standard PHP serializer library... you can totally adhoc it. Just make sure that you get the concept and that you use proper JSON formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You may change few things here like:-

```js
$(function(){
  
  const $input = $('.tag-editor');
  const jsString = $input.attr("data-attributes-js");
  const jsObj = JSON.parse(jsString);
  
  console.log(jsObj);;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="tag-editor" type="text" name="xxxx" data-attributes-js='{"placeholder":"1,2,3,4","other_para":true,"another_para":5}'></textarea>
```

Comment: not working: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0**

Comment: is your attribute like - data-attributes-js='{"placeholder":"1,2,3,4","other_para":true,"another_para":5}'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what capabilities you have at your PHP server but in general:

1. create a real object then stringify it
2. send it over as a JSON string
3. parse the JSON back into an object
4. pass the object to `.tag-editor()`

```js
/* Server Back-end */
/* 
this is not code for server -- it's just to provide the JSON string that would come 
from a server for demonstration purposes.
*/

let object = {initialTags: ["object", "json-stringify", "data", "json-parse", "tag-editor"]};

let data = JSON.stringify(object); 

/* Client Front-end */

$(".tag-editor").data('attributes-js', data);

data = $(".tag-editor").data('attributes-js');

object = JSON.parse(data);
  
$(".tag-editor").tagEditor(object);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.min.css" />

<textarea class="tag-editor"></textarea>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tag-editor/1.0.20/jquery.tag-editor.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not the case, I just want this answer to work but it does not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399563/javascript-params-from-string-value#answer-56400835

Comment: Did you run the example by clicking the blue button? Did you read this part: *"this is not code for server -- it's just to provide the JSON string that would come 
from a server for demonstration purposes."* You see if you get a JSON from the server (like most clients do) you can take that string and convert it to an object. An object is something that plugin will accept.

Comment: The reason why this happens: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0` is because the JSON was never an object. You are applying apples with `<textarea...data-att="heyLookAtMeImAnOBJECTBelieveIt: butImReallyAString">` when you need an orange `let json = {"heyLookAtMeImAnOBJECT": "REAL"};`

Comment: in mY  PHP `array(
   'id'      => 'opt-tag-3',
   'title'   => 'With attributes (placeholder)',
   'type'    => 'tag',
   'default' => '',
   'attributes_js' => array(
    'placeholder' => " 'Enter a term' ",
   )
  ),` and in my html print `<textarea class="tag-editor" type="text" name="pixel2[opt-tag-3]"  data-attributes-js="{ placeholder : 'Enter a term'}"></textarea>` How do I make the parameters of a string turn them into objects and execute them in the tagEditor plugin?

Comment: That sounds like a PHP question...actually in its entirety more like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). The string should be an object originally. Copy my demo and remove the the first two lines and add the following in their place: `let data = \`{initialTags: ["object", "json-stringify", "data", "json-parse", "tag-editor"]}\`;` You should get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Correction the replacement line should be : `let data = '{"initialTags": ["object", "json-stringify", "data", "json-parse", "tag-editor"]}'`